# DB::table()-> select() ->where()->get(); Laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I am trying here to select a data by id from a table, but only where certain other things exist. And it is just not working! I am thinking the problem lays in my database query. It either doesn't show me anything or only the first book.
I hope someone can help me, I really tried everything!

In my Model I tried:

```
public static function myWishlist(){
$id = Auth::id();
```

---

```
$book_id = DB::table('wishlist')->select('book_id')
        ->where('user_id' ,  '=' ,  $id)
        ->get();
    foreach ($book_id as $book){
    return Book::where('id', $book);
```

---

```
$book_id= Wishlist::select('book_id')
->where('user_id', $id)
->get()->all();
```

---

```
$book_id = DB::table('wishlist')
->where('user_id', $id)
->get('book_id');//->toArray();
```

---

```
$book_id = DB::table('wishlist')
->select('book_id')
->where('user_id', $id)->first();
```

}

I would be so happy for some help!

Comment: `foreach ($book_id as $book){
    return Book::where('id', $book);}` this screams "code smell" so loudly my screen almost cracked.

Comment: You lack basic understanding of PHP, please go back a little or see some tutorial first. Your code does not make sense, your commentary above does not make sense either.

Comment: What exactly do you want? what did you currently have? What have you tried? what result did you get when you tried it? If you can answer this questions. It would be easy for someone to help out.

Comment: Can you give the complete function where you have this code?

Comment: I really really dont understand what you are talking about @Kyslik and Loek

Comment: Yes I can! I just thought thats all whats needed. If the query was wrong! Since I thought the error lays in there.

Comment: @Loek ⬆ (7 more to go)

Comment: So show us the error you got, and what you expected.

Comment: It means you REALLY need to look at the docs closer before you start asking questions. The syntax you are using isn't remotely close to what it should be.

Comment: This is returning just the first element of the loop, that's why you get only one element. if you `dd($book_id);` before `for`, you should see the full collection.

Comment: @L.Lehmann You never ever ever ever return stuff from inside for-loops. Maybe there are very low level hacks where this might be useful, but it's something a good programmer conciously writes maybe three or four times in his career. Your code works for the most part, but it isn't very readable and it's obvious you just started programming. Maybe I overreacted a little with my first comment, sorry for that, but try to get a good basis in programming before attempting relatively advanced stuff like what your question is about.

Comment: I see Loek. I will remember that

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
$book_id = Wishlist::where('user_id', $id)->pluck('book_id');

return Book::whereIn('id',$book_id)->get();
```

Comment: I will try that! Thank you

Comment: When I do that, and then want to index it with: $books = Wishlist::myWishlist()->paginate(20); 
        return view('wishlistCRUD.index', compact('books'))
            ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
I get the error: method paginate does not exist. Could you also help me with that?

Comment: im not sure but its because myWishlist() function on model Wishlist doesnot collects data from model.Please consider this.